# What exactly is the class complexity

Tags: sonarqube, metrics, cyclomatic-complexity

Their wiki only says the obvious (average complexity of the class), but what does it actually mean?

I know for method complexity, 15-20 is usually the upper bound for a testable and maintainable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a lot with Cyclomatic Complexity. Here are some posts on my blog but you could find much more:
http://qualilogy.com/en/legacy-c-application-refactoring-reengineering-1/ and 
http://qualilogy.com/en/legacy-application-refactoring-reengineering-7/

Yes, per class/file it is an average of the complexity of each method/function:
http://qualilogy.com/en/legacy-application-refactoring-sqale-plugin-1/

Comment: Thanks. What I do not understad is how can I get higher CC in file than in class (we get 17 for classes but 22 for files). As files are comprised with classes, how it can be higher?

Comment: Is is Java code? Are  you sure you don't have 2 classes in the same file?